Firebase getRedirectResult() not being called after multiple logins (user is null)
I'm using the Firebase Auth SDK, however, sometimes a valid Google account isn't valid for my application (need it to be a specific type), so my Flask endpoint rejects it, at which point the user should login again. Upon the second login, getRedirectResult() is returning null for user. It works fine for the first login, but after signing out, the 2nd login has user = null.
Activated by button press in index.html:
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
window.login = function() {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email');
    provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile');
    provider.setCustomParameters({
      prompt: 'select_account'
    });
    signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
  }

Called by signInWithRedirect independently (in index.html):
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    getRedirectResult(auth)
      .then((result) => {
        console.log('RESULT FOUND FROM GETREDIRECT');
        console.log(result);
        // console.log(result.user);
        if (result && result.user) {
          const user = result.user;
          console.dir(result);
          debugger;
          fetch('/handle_login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              uid: user.uid,
              email: user.email,
              displayName: user.displayName,
              idToken: result._tokenResponse.idToken,
              refreshToken: result._tokenResponse.refreshToken
            })
          }).then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
              logout();
              console.error("Error returned by /handle_login:", response);
              alert('Must use NJIT email to login');
              window.location.href = '/login';
            } else {
              window.location.href = '/';
            }
          }).catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error during handle_login:", error);
            alert('Must use NJIT email to login');
            window.location.href = '/login';
          });
        }
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error during getRedirectResult:", error);
      });
  });

In a separate file (extended via jinja extend base.html):
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth();
window.logout = function() {
            signOut(auth).then(() => {
            // Make a POST request to the Flask server to handle the logout
            console.log('Firebase signOut(auth) successful');
            fetch('/logout', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    window.location.href = '/';
                } else {
                    throw new Error('Failed to log out');
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error during logout:", error);
            });
        }).catch((error) => {
            // error in signout
            console.error("Error during signout:", error);
        });
    }


I've seen similar questions abt user being null and have tried onAuthStateChanged but the same behavior occurs where user stays null on second sign in

As a temporary fix, I've replaced signInWithRedirect with signInWithPopup, which returns a Promise so you can tie the .then((result) =>... directly, removing the need for getRedirectResult or onAuthStateChanged
